# Filter non empty members on row

Tags: mdx

I have the following MDX query:

```
select 
    NON EMPTY [Measures].Members ON COLUMNS, 
    NON EMPTY {[MY_DIMENSION.MY_HIERARCHY].[VALUE].Members}  ON ROWS 
from 
    [MY_CUBE]
```

It gives the following result:

```
                                    [Measures].[COUNT_TICKET] 
-------------------------------------------------------------
[MY_DIMENSION.MY_HIERARCHY].[#null]                14 333 458  (<-- not needed)
[MY_DIMENSION.MY_HIERARCHY].[VAL1]                      4 864
[MY_DIMENSION.MY_HIERARCHY].[VAL2]                      5 588
[MY_DIMENSION.MY_HIERARCHY].[VAL3]                      2 567
[MY_DIMENSION.MY_HIERARCHY].[VAL3]                      4 500
```

Which takes a long time because there are a big number of null values out there.

Is it possible to filter the `#null` Members of my hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
select 
NON EMPTY {[Measures].Members} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY {[MY_DIMENSION.MY_HIERARCHY].[VALUE].Members}  ON ROWS
```

from 
    [MY_CUBE]

Comment: doesn't help, same result :(

Comment: Try [MY_DIMENSION.MY_HIERARCHY].CHILDREN instead with the same NonEmpty as I showed you in the answer and see if it eliminates nulls.

Comment: thanks again for the answer. I'll give it a try tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: How are you handling nulls when you process the cube?